# Google Maps Synchronization and Set Interval onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, google-maps-api-3

I'm stuck with a situation where i need to

1. How can i use the Ajax call to get the json result from my MVC 3 Controller?
2. Must continue Looping Even the Result returns Zero_Results at Google
   Maps because it stops looping when the result is Zero_Results

This is my Code in my Script file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var geocoder;
    var map;

    function initialize() {
        var minZoomLevel = 4;
        var zooms = 7;
        geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: minZoomLevel,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(38.50, -90.50),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });

        // Bounds for North America
        var strictBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(
     new google.maps.LatLng(15.70, -160.50),
     new google.maps.LatLng(68.85, -55.90)
   );

        // Listen for the dragend event
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function () {
            if (strictBounds.contains(map.getCenter())) return;

            // We're out of bounds - Move the map back within the bounds

            var c = map.getCenter(),
         x = c.lng(),
         y = c.lat(),
         maxX = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lng(),
         maxY = strictBounds.getNorthEast().lat(),
         minX = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lng(),
         minY = strictBounds.getSouthWest().lat();

            if (x < minX) x = minX;
            if (x > maxX) x = maxX;
            if (y < minY) y = minY;
            if (y > maxY) y = maxY;

            map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(y, x));
        });


        // Limit the zoom level
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
            if (map.getZoom() < minZoomLevel) map.setZoom(minZoomLevel);
        });


    }
    var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
function codeAddress() {
        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var address = $('#workerGrid').find("input[name=shiftDay]");
        $.each(address, function () {
            var currVal = $(this).val();

                geocoder.geocode({ 'address': currVal }, function (results, status) {
                    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            map: map,
                            icon: iconBase + 'man.png',
                            position: results[0].geometry.location,
                            title: currVal
                        })


                        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
                            return function () {
                                infowindow.setContent(currVal);
                                infowindow.open(map, marker);
                            }
                        })(marker, currVal));
                        address.push(marker);
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                    }
                });

        });
        return true;
    }

    window.onload = function () {
        initialize();
        codeAddress();

    }

</script>
```

This is my Controller where i get the Array of Worker

```
public JsonResult LoadWorkerList()
        {
            var workerList = new List<Worker_Address>();

            // check if search string has value
            // retrieve list of workers filtered by search criteria
            var list = (from a in db.Worker_Address
                        where a.LogicalDelete == false
                        select a).ToList();



            List<WorkerAddressInfo> wlist = new List<WorkerAddressInfo>();
            foreach (var row in list)
            {
                WorkerAddressInfo ci = new WorkerAddressInfo
                {
                    ID = row.ID,
                    Worker_ID = row.WorkerID,
                    AddressLine1 = row.Address_Line1 + " " + row.Address_Line2+ " " +row.City + " "+ GetLookupDisplayValById(row.State_LookID),
                    //AddressLine2 = row.Address_Line2,
                    //City = row.City,
                    //State = GetLookupDisplayValById(row.State_LookID),
                    LogicalDelete = row.LogicalDelete

                };
                wlist.Add(ci);
            }


            return Json(wlist.ToList().OrderBy(p => p.AddressLine1), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Thanks in Advance :)